I have hidden vertices and I don't know what to do
I'm new to Blender. I followed some tutorials from YouTube and now I try to copy a random character from Artstation to test my newbie skills.
I've made a low poly head and now I try to smooth it with the smooth tool. When I do that, my head splits. I think there are some hidden vertices that wont show up in vertex select. I don't know what to do now, if I should delete them, connect them or make the head again.
Before using the smooth tool and after using it.



Select two vertices, that should be a single vertex, Press M (merge) and choose "at center" to merge the two vertices at the center of their positions. Repeat this for alle other disconnected vertices.

thank you so much!!!!!!1

or press Alt+H to unhide hidden vertices, then select all vertices and press M for Merge By Distance. This removes vertices that are very close, so-called duplicated vertices
